# How to make the csv file downloadable in magento?

Tags: magento, csv, magento-1.7

I am fetching some of the products information and storing it to a variable, than I am writing that variable in csv file.

```
$mage_csv->saveData($file_path, $products_fields);
```

But now I want to do something like, when some one clicks on a button, download window should appear and that csv file should be downloaded. What should I do? Please any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing backend controller. You can use `_prepareDownloadResponse` like this

```
$data = 'your csv data';
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse('file.csv', $data, 'text/csv');
```

Comment: Where to right this code? all the data is fetched from the template file, so I am trying to achieve like if i can code in template only and achieve the task, Is it possible?

Comment: You should write this code in controller like this.

    class MyModule_SampleController extends Mage_Adminhmtl_Controller_Front_Action {
        public function download() {
            ...
            $data = 'your csv data';
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('file.csv', $data, 'text/csv');
        }
    }

Comment: are ok, i got it. I am creating whole module now, thanx for the advice. :)

Comment: It worked. thanx, I did some changes but its all working now.!